Generalization of $\max$ and $\min$ of $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2$ with given $x^2+y^2=k$.

Generalization of $\max / \min (Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2)$ with given $x^2+y^2=k$. ($A, C > 0$)

My first thought was drawing an ellipse and circle of each of the 2 given equations and think about the intersections the two shapes make.
\begin{align}
& \text{let the ellipse be defined as: } \\
& Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0. \\
\Rightarrow \; & 
\begin{cases}
A = a^2sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta & B = 2(b^2-a^2)\sin\theta\cos\theta \\
C = a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta & D = -2Ax_0-By_0 \\
E = -Bx_0-2Cy_0 & F = A{x_0}^2+Bx_0y_0+C{y_0}^2-a^2
\end{cases}, \\
& \text{where $a$ is semi-major axis, $b$ is the semi-minor axis,} \\
& \text{$(x_0, y_0)$ is the center coordinates, and $\theta$ is the rotation angle.} \\
& \cdots
\end{align}
…It seemed too hard and involved to me.
Then my second thought was to make it with trigonometry…
\begin{align}
& x = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos\theta, y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sin\theta. \\
\Rightarrow \; & Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=(x^2+y^2)(A\cos^2\theta+B\cos\theta\sin\theta+C\sin^2\theta) \\
=\;&k(A\cos^2\theta+B\cos\theta\sin\theta+C\sin^2\theta) \\
=\;&kA\dfrac{\cos(2\theta)+1}{2}+kB\dfrac{\sin(2\theta)}{2}+kC\dfrac{-\cos(2\theta)+1}{2} \\
=\;& \dfrac{k(A+C)}{2}+\dfrac{k(A-C)}{2}\cos(2\theta)+\dfrac{kB}{2}\sin(2\theta) \\
\ \\
&\text{let }
\begin{cases} \dfrac{A-C}{\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}}=\sin\gamma \\ \dfrac{B}{\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}}=\cos\gamma
\end{cases}. \\
\ \\
\Rightarrow \; & Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 \\
=\;& \dfrac{k(A+C)}{2}+\dfrac{k}{2}\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2} (\cos(2\theta)\sin\gamma+\sin(2\theta)\cos\gamma) \\
=\;& \dfrac{k(A+C)}{2}+\dfrac{k}{2}\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}\sin(2\theta+\gamma) \\
\in \;& \left[\dfrac{k(A+C)}{2}-\dfrac{k}{2}\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}, \dfrac{k(A+C)}{2}+\dfrac{k}{2}\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}\right]
\end{align}
Yeah, so did I solved this… but this also seems too complicated.
Are there other simpler solutions to this, and is the answer I’ve got right?

You can rotate the picture to make $B = 0$. When you do so the determinant $B^2 - 4AC$ and the trace $A + C$ are unchanged. In other words, if the function $Ax^2 + Bxy + C^2y^2$  transforms into $A' x^2 + C' y^2$, then you will have
$$ -4A'C' = B^2 - 4AC$$
$$A' + C' = A + C$$
So $A'$ and $C'$ are the roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ to the quadratic equation
$$r^2 - (A + C) r + AC - \frac{B^2}{4} = 0$$
So now you want the maximum and minimum of $r_1 x^2 + r_2 y^2$ on the
circle $x^2 + y^2 = k$, which is unchanged under the rotation. These occur on the $x$ and $y$ axes, so are given by $r_1 k$ and $r_2 k$. The larger is the maximum and the smaller is the minimum.
It looks like your answer was almost right... the term ${\displaystyle {k(A - C) \over 2}}$ should have been ${\displaystyle {k(A + C) \over 2}}$ but looks otherwise OK.

Yep… your last words are right. I’ve made a prominent mistake :)

The linear algebra way to do this is to evaluate the objective as.
$x^T\pmatrix {A & \frac {B}{2}\\\frac {B}{2} & C} x^T$
And the maximum will be associated with the largest eigenvalue.  The minimum will be associated with the smallest eigenvalue.
$\lambda^2 - (A+C)\lambda + \frac {4AC - B^2}{4} = 0$
$\lambda = \frac {(A+C) \pm \sqrt {(A+C)^2 - 4AC + B^2}}{2}$
$\lambda = \frac {(A+C) \pm \sqrt {A^2 + B^2 + C^2 - 2AC}}{2}$
The extreme values evaluate to $\lambda k$
The maximum / minimum will be determined by the sign of the $\pm.$
An approach occurred to me that gets to the same equation without using linear algebra, in case you have not learned that.
Let M be the maximum of $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2$
i.e.  for some $x,y$, $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 = M$
From the constraint $\frac {M}{k}x^2 + \frac {M}{k} y^2 = M$
Let $\lambda = \frac {M}{k}$
Then $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 = \lambda x^2 + \lambda y^2$
Or $(A-\lambda)x^2 + Bxy + (C-\lambda)y^2 = 0$
Plug this into the quadratic formula.
$x = \frac {-B \pm \sqrt {B^2 - 4(A-\lambda)(C-\lambda)}}{2A}y$
Since we are at the maximum the discriminant is $0.$ i.e. the conic is tangent to the constraining circle.
$B^2 - 4(A-\lambda)(C-\lambda) = 0$
$\lambda^2 - (A-C)\lambda + AC - \frac {B^2}{4} = 0$
As above.

Eliminating $x$ in
$$
\cases{
z = A x^2+B x y +C y^2\\
x^2+y^2=k
}
$$
we obtain
$$
p(y) = A^2 k^2-2 A^2 k y^2+A^2 y^4+2 A C k y^2-2 A C y^4-2 A k z+2 A y^2 z-B^2 k y^2+B^2 y^4+C^2 y^4-2 C y^2 z+z^2
$$
now, at the $\min/\max$ of $z$ we have that $p(y)$ should have a double root or
$$
p(y) = c_1(y-y_1)^2(y^2+c_2 y + c_3)\ \ \forall y
$$
which is equivalent to solve for $\{c_1,c_2,c_3,y_1,z\}$ the system of coefficients
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 A^2 k^2-2 A k z-c_1 c_3 y_1^2+z^2 & = & 0 \\
 2 c_1 c_3 y_1-c_1 c_2 y_1^2  & = & 0 \\
 -2 A^2 k+2 A C k+2 A z-B^2 k-2 C z+2 c_1 c_2 y_1-c_1 c_3-c_1 y_1^2  & = & 0 \\
 2 c_1 y_1-c_1 c_2  & = & 0 \\
 A^2-2 A C+B^2+C^2-c_1  & = & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and thus obtaining
$$
z^* = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 A k \\
 \frac{1}{2} k (A+C)+k|A-C|\frac{\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}}{2 (A-C)} \\
 \frac{1}{2} k (A+C)-k|A-C|\frac{\sqrt{ (A-C)^2+B^2}}{2 (A-C)} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
